# Why won't my react variable render on the DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I am learning react and am using this github repository from the official React website [create-react](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app)

I have followed the instructions and began editing the `App.js` that is provided.

In my App.js file I am creating a `Todo` class and rendering it on the DOM with the `#container` id.

Here is the `App.js` file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

var Todo = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <h1 className="todo">Hello</h1>
    );
  }
});

export default App;
```

Here is the `index.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Todo />,
  document.getElementbyId('container')
);
```

And here is the `index.html` file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./src/favicon.ico">
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id="container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I open the web page I get this error `21:5  warning  'Todo' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars`

What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to export the `Todo` variable (a React class) along with the `App` component. To do this use `export` followed by braces and the things you want to export:

```
export {
    Todo,
    App
};
```

This makes this public and importable. Both are now able to be use in a different file. Import like this:

```
import { App, Todo } from './App';
```

This will import both of the exported components and you will be able to access them both. Then render like you always do:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Todo />,
    document.getElementbyId('container')
);
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew. This finally worked for me. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Hey i think you need to export TODO from app.js and import TODO in index.js

`export const Todo` (in app.js)

```
import Todo from "./app";(in index.js)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Lionel. Unfortunately it didn't work. Adding `export const Todo;` gave me an error `Syntax error: Unexpected token (29:17)`

Comment: That's because a var can't be exported as a const. You need to plainly export it. @DanRubio